# How to make onselectstart enabled only in one div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, onselect, oncopy

I blocked copying and selecting of text and elements on my website:

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false" onselectstart="return false" onselect="return false" oncopy="return false">
```

But now I need to enable it in only one div so I tried:

```
<div class="somediv" oncontextmenu="" onselectstart="" onselect="" oncopy="">You can select and copy that text.</div>
```

And of course it is not working. How can I enable it? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the first line of html is overriding what you're trying to do in the second line of html.

Comment: I know it too and I need help to solve that problem.